# what's wrong in this custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I am creating a custom dialog that will show the information of a food item:
the xml layout for the dialog is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >           
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/lblCal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/lblFat" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/lblCarb" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TableRow 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text=" OK " 
        android:id="@+id/btnOK" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Home" 
        android:id="@+id/btnHome" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

the onCreatDialog method is defined like this:

```
@Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
      Dialog d;
      switch (id) {
        case 0:
            d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.result_dialog);               
            d.setTitle(item);
            TextView lblEnergy = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblCal);                
            lblEnergy.setText("Energy: "+ String.valueOf(cal));
            TextView lblFat = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblCal);               
            lblFat.setText("Fat: "+  String.valueOf(fat));
            TextView lblCarbs = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblCal);             
            lblCarbs.setText("Carbs: " + String.valueOf(carb));
            Button ok = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);            
            ok.setOnClickListener(i);
            Button home = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnHome);            
            home.setOnClickListener(i);
            break;
            default: d = null;
      }
    return d;
  }
```

but when I run the program the first two textview don't appear.

**what is the problem?!!**

what I should add to the ok button to close the dialog,  because when I call DissmisDialog(0);
when I click again on another item the dialog contents never changed

Comment: I also have a problem with onClickListener, when I write the code:( case R.id.btnHome:
 startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_DietTracker.class));break;)   it give me an error for (this), can I put getApplicationContext()

Comment: Another problem with your layout: you are using a TableRow just out of nowhere: "A TableRow should always be used as a child of a TableLayout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the correct ids for the `findViewById` calls:

Old:

```
        TextView lblEnergy = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblCal);                
        lblEnergy.setText("Energy: "+ String.valueOf(cal));
        TextView lblFat = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblCal);               
        lblFat.setText("Fat: "+  String.valueOf(fat));
        TextView lblCarbs = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblCal);             
        lblCarbs.setText("Carbs: " + String.valueOf(carb));
```

New:

```
        TextView lblEnergy = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblCal);                
        lblEnergy.setText("Energy: "+ String.valueOf(cal));
        TextView lblFat = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblFat /* <<< */);               
        lblFat.setText("Fat: "+  String.valueOf(fat));
        TextView lblCarbs = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.lblCarb /* <<< */);             
        lblCarbs.setText("Carbs: " + String.valueOf(carb));
```